# Text: remove empty space at top or get its size

Tags: qt, fonts, qml

I want to center vertically image and text. But when I'm trying to, it does not look centered, because of an empty space at the top of the text.

What I mean is illustrated by this image:

[image]

The blue rectangle looks a bit above the text. However, these two controls are centered actually. The second image illustrates this by showing text's bounding rectangle.

[image]

Is there any way to remove this few empty lines of pixels at the top in the text control? Or at least somehow get its height so I can take this into account manually?

Here is the QML code for these two images:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property string myText: "SOME TEST TEXT"
    property int myFontPixelSize: 13

    ColumnLayout
    {
        spacing: 20

        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.leftMargin: 10
        anchors.topMargin: 10

        RowLayout
        {
            spacing: 5

            Rectangle
            {
                color: "blue"
                Layout.preferredWidth: 13
                Layout.preferredHeight: 12
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
            }

            Label
            {
                text: "<a href='https://bugreports.qt.io'>" + myText + "</a>"
                font.pixelSize: myFontPixelSize
                font.family: "Arial"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
            }
        }

        RowLayout
        {
            spacing: 5

            Rectangle
            {
                color: "blue"
                Layout.preferredWidth: 13
                Layout.preferredHeight: 12
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
            }

            Label
            {
                text: "<a href='https://bugreports.qt.io'>" + myText + "</a>"
                font.pixelSize: myFontPixelSize
                font.family: "Arial"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
                Rectangle{anchors.fill: parent; color:"black";z:-1}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens to that space when you enlarge the text font? Try something big, like size 48 or 64. If the space doesn't grow then you would probably need to add some platform-specific "fudge constants" to make it work. If the space does grow then you'll be able to figure out what font metric it corresponds to (see `QFontMetric`).

Comment: How does it look when the text is not a link? It appears that the text is centered, but the underline from the link makes it appear not vertically centered.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica It does grow. Unfortunately, I do not see any suitable value in `FontMetrics`.

Comment: @DFaller Thank you for the notice. Now I've decided to just use `Layout.topMargin: Math.max(1, FontMetrics.lineWidth/2)` for my image.

Comment: I've run into this problem too. Some fonts are really bad. It's because some characters within the font might use that extra space, even if the ones you're using do not. It would be nice if there was a way to manually constrain the ascent or descent of a font in Qt. With my projects, it has usually looked better if I set the `Label`'s height equal to the font's `ascent` value. But that's not guaranteed to work with every font.